# Splash Screen animation not proper

Tags: android, animation

I want an animation as shown in the following app's Splash Screen
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.carsake.venetianhonda&hl=en
as well as the animation of button which appears on click of floating action button

I already tried https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewAnimations, but none of the animation matches.I even tried on my own.Foll is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:zAdjustment="top"
        android:duration="2000"
        android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="200%"
        android:toXDelta="50%"
        android:fromXDelta="100%"/>

</set>
```

Please help

Comment: see this https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton

Comment: Do you know what animation they applied to splash screen?

Comment: no  for that i have to install it? i just give about menu animation

Comment: the library is deprectaed